# SSH 'Host key verification failed' error

Tags: linux, ssh, git, openssh

I've generated my ssh key and uploaded it to my github account.

What I do was copy directly my id_rsa.pub to my github account. I've verified the key to my local key using `ssh-add -l`, it was the same.

Then I try to connect to github using the command:
`ssh -vT git@github.com`
I get the following messages:

> OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
>
> debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
>
> debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
>
> debug1: Connecting to github.com [204.232.175.90] port 22.
>
> debug1: Connection established.
>
> debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
>
> debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
>
> debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
>
> debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
>
> debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
>
> debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
>
> debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
>
> debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze1+github12
>
> debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze1+github12 pat OpenSSH*
>
> debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
>
> debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
>
> debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
>
> debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
>
> debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
>
> debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
>
> debug1: Server host key: RSA 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48
>
> The authenticity of host 'github.com (204.232.175.90)' can't be established.
>
> RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
>
> Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

I pressed 'enter', then I got the message:

> Host key verification failed.

Just for information, I've installed openssh-client. I never succeeded to connect before. Besides, in my .ssh folder, the file known_hosts was never automatically generated. Even if I create manually the empty file, it still doesn't work.

Comment: What was specifically hard to understand with "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?"? The parentheses suggest what you are expected to enter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to type "yes" when it asks you to verify the host key.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for making such a stupid mistake. However I got Permission denied (publickey) now... but I think I can try to search the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate an SSH key.

Follow these instructions:

[Error: Permission Denied Publickey](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey)

Comment: Try to add the instructions to your post, it will help if links expire.